# Getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

I have added my code below. I keep getting this error. I have only one spreadsheet open on my browser and the apps script was open from there so they should be linked but I can't seem to get past the first line. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function Search() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shtDonnees = ss.getSheetByName("Donnees");
var shtRecherche = ss.getSheetByName("Recherche");
var Donnees = shtDonnees.getDataRange ().getValues();
var sField = shtRecherche.getRange("A2").getValue();
var sValue = shtRecherche.getRange("A5").getValue();
var sIndex = Donnees[0].indexOf(sField);

var results = Donnees.filter(function (e){return e[sIndex] == sValue});

shtRecherche.getRange(2, 3, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results)
.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);




}
```

I am trying to create a button which will search my data

Comment: Did you check your typing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. but i am now stuck on the following [var shtDonnees = ss.getSpreadsheetByName("Donnees");], do you have any ideas as to how I can fix this error @TheWizEd thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not clear what you mean. Please post a new question including a [mcve]. Besides adding the code briefly descript your spreadsheet, more specífically what are the name of the sheet. Play special attention to the exact spelling, incluiding spaces .

Comment: A note about editing questions, the edit feature is intended to improve the post, not to making changes that completely change what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `getSheetByName` ? Cause `getSpreadsheetByName` does not exist.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

**EDIT:**
(normally, you should open another thread for the `length` issue cause it was not the original title and the original bug)

most likely, `results.length` works fine and `results[0].length` throws the error because, I guess, `results` is an empty array (so there is no element at index 0).

1. Check that `Donnees` has the data you expect
2. Check your condition in the `filter`.
3. Check the content of `results` before assuming there are elements in it

Comment: Thank you @VaILeNain. I am also getting the error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined) do you know what in my code could be causing this?

Comment: `var Donnees = shtDonnees.getDataRange ().getValues();` : is the space after `getDataRange` also present in your code ? try to `console.log` the content of `Donnees` to see what's inside. Try to also log what is in `results`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I am trying to do what is on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-12ivKg0Vu8 but no matter how i type it, it does not work but it works in this video explaining how to do it.

Comment: @Dasilva Start by using the same code shown in the video, letter by letter, as well apply the same sheet formatting, cell by cell. Once you get it working play making changes.

Comment: ValLeNain: please avoid to use labels like "edit", instead you might divide your post in sections by including more meaningful headings or an horizontal line. P.S. Also consider to rollback the question to the corresponding revision when question edits have invalidated a good answer.